# How to sort and email posted input variables

Tags: php, html

I have a post form where I am collecting a handful of data from a user input. When all of the data is posted, I want to email a confirmation to the user and myself. I also want the page to redirect to a separate page which would re display the inputted data back to the user. Here are the questions I have.

1. What is the best practice to email all my data? Is it a bad idea to use **isset()** to wait for all of them to be filled out then the **mail()** function?
2. How can I make the yes / no radio inputs under '**Physical Activity Readiness Questionnaire**' appear next to each other instead of on top of each other?
3. Under '**General & Medical Questionnaire**', If a user selects '**no**' for '**Occupational Questions**', is it possible to void / darken the following 5 questions? (I want '**Occupational questions**' to serve as a toggle)

The site is available here: http://macrorevolution.com/health/

--Ignore the php code, it is irrelevant-- 
Here is the code (skip to html section):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: healthquestions
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $al_options = get_option('al_general_settings');?>
<!-- Title -->

<div class="box pt20">

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="headertext">

        <?php the_title() ?>

        <?php $headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_headline", $single = false);?>

        <?php if(!empty($headline[0]) ):?>

            <span><?php echo $headline[0] ?></span>

        <?php endif?>

    </div>

    <div class="clearsmall"></div>



    <!-- Promo text -->

    <?php $promo = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_promo", $single = false);?>

    <?php if(!empty($promo[0]) ):?>

       <div class="calloutcontainer">

            <div class="container_12">

                <div class="grid_12">            

                    <?php echo do_shortcode($promo[0]);?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>    

    <?php endif?>

    <div class="container_12">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-------PHP CODE------------------------------>
<?php
$goalbodyfatv = "";
$weightv = "";
$bodyfatv = "";
$answer="";
if(isset($_POST['weightv']) && isset($_POST['bodyfatv']) && isset($_POST['goalbodyfatv'])) {

    $weightv = $_POST['weightv'];
    $bodyfatv = $_POST['bodyfatv'];
    $goalbodyfatv = $_POST['goalbodyfatv'];
    $weightkg = $weightv/2.2;
    $answer = ($weightv * $bodyfatv)-($weightv * $goalbodyfatv);

}
?>
<!----------CSS CODE-------------------------->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>Fat Loss Calculator</title>
<style>
  table {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  }
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
  padding:0em 1em 1em 0em;

}
p.ss {
    font-size:30px; 
    text-align:center
}
input {
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box pt20">
<p class="ss">health title</p><br>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan="4">
description here
    </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<!-------------HTML CODE STARTS HERE--------------------->
<!-----------Contact information------------------>
<form method='post' action=''>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan='2'>First name: <input type='text' name='fname' value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;Last name<input type='text' name='lname' value="<?php echo $lname; ?>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: <input type='text' name='email' size='16' value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan='2'>Age: <input type='text' name='age' size='6' value="<?php echo $age; ?>"/> Years &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Height: <input type='text' name='height' size='6' value="<?php echo $heightft; ?>"/> ft. <input type='text' name='age' size='5' value="<?php echo $heightin; ?>"/> in.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight: <input type='text' name='weight' size='6' value="<?php echo $weight; ?>"/> lbs. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!----------------Physical/Activity Readiness--------------------->
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'><p style="font-size:25px"><strong>Physical Activity Readiness Questionnaire</strong></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>1. Has your doctor ever said that you have a heart condition and that you should
only perform physical activity recommended by a doctor?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q1' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q1' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>2. Do you feel pain in your chest when you perform physical activity?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q2' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q2' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>3. In the past month, have you had chest pain when you were not performing any
physical activity?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q3' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q3' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>4. Do you lose your balance because of dizziness or do you ever lose
consciousness?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q4' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q4' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>
5. Do you have a bone or joint problem that could be made worse by a change in
your physical activity?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q5' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q5' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>
6. Is your doctor currently prescribing any medication for your blood pressure or
for a heart condition?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q6' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q6' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan='2'>
7. Do you know of any other reason why you should not engage in physical
activity?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='q7' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='q7' value='no'>No
    </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td width='100%'>**********If you have answered “Yes” to one or more of the above questions, consult your physician before
engaging in physical activity. Tell your physician which questions you answered “Yes” to. After a
medical evaluation, seek advice from your physician on what type of activity is suitable for your
current condition.</td></tr>
</table>
<!----------------------General&Med---------------------------------->
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td><p style="font-size:25px"><strong>General & Medical Questionnaire</strong></p></td></tr>

    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td><strong>Occupational Questions</strong>
    <input type='radio' name='oyesno' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='oyesno' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>1. What is your current occupation?<input type='text' name='occ1' value="<?php echo $occ1; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td>2. Does your occupation require extended periods of sitting?    
    <input type='radio' name='o2' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='o2' value='no'>No</td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>3. Does your occupation require extended periods of repetitive movements? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='occ3' size='20' value="<?php echo $occ3; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='o3' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='o3' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td>4. Does your occupation require you to wear shoes with a heel (dress shoes)?
    <input type='radio' name='o4' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='o4' value='no'>No</td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td>5. Does your occupation cause you anxiety (mental stress)?
    <input type='radio' name='o5' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='o5' value='no'>No</td></tr>    

<!------------Recreational Questions------------------------------>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td><strong>Recreational Questions</strong>
    <input type='radio' name='ryesno' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='ryesno' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>1. Do you partake in any recreational activities (golf, tennis, skiing, etc.)? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='rec1' size='20' value="<?php echo $rec1; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='r1' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='r1' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>2. Do you have any hobbies (reading, gardening, working on cars, exploring the Internet, etc.)? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='rec2' size='20' value="<?php echo $rec2; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='r2' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='r2' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>    
<!-------------Medical Questions--------------------------->
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td><strong>Medical Questions</strong>
    <input type='radio' name='myesno' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='myesno' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>1. Have you ever had any pain or injuries (ankle, knee, hip, back, shoulder, etc.)? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='med1' size='20' value="<?php echo $med1; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='m1' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='m1' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>2. Have you ever had surgeries? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='med2' size='20' value="<?php echo $med2; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='m2' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='m2' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>3. Has a medical doctor ever diagnosed you with a chronic disease such as coronary heart disease, coronary artery disease, hypertension (high blood pressure), high cholesterol, or diabetes? (if yes, please explain) <input type='text' name='med3' size='20' value="<?php echo $med3; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='m3' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='m3' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>
    <tr class='spaceUnder'><td colspan='2'>4. Are you currently taking any medication? (if yes, please list) <input type='text' name='med4' size='20' value="<?php echo $med4; ?>"/></td><td>
    <input type='radio' name='m4' value='yes'>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='m4' value='no'>No
    </td></tr>        

<!--------------------submit button-------------------------------->
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' class="button highlight small" value='Submit'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: sending medical data around in such an insecure way is  bad practice, and potentially illegal in some jurisdictions

Comment: Is there a different way you recommend? How do I go about securing it @Dagon

Comment: nothing should be in an email that you wouldn't write on the outside of  postcard. you should store it securely and access it securely (they are very large topics and outside of the scope here)